# Reactive way of resizing images from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, asynchronous, gridfs, reactivemongo

I'm looking for a reactive way to resize images which are stored in GridFS.

There is an article [here](http://www.wilmontech.com/upload-and-resize-images/) but unfortunately it uses Casbah which is not non-bloking.

And also there is a [good library](https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage) for image resizing. Although it supports async operations, I couldn't find a way to resize an image chunk-by-chunk. Maybe it's not possible at all. Then I'm OK but would you please help me to understand how can I convert an Enumerator (which I get from GridFS) to a simple stream which is usable by scrimage (image resizer lib).

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I have to start with, ( and I find I always do ) is to bring to your consideration of why you are using GridFS in the first place.

This comes from, as I have stated before, a common misconception that GridFS is how MongoDB stores files, and therefore that is what you use. So I recommend to anyone considering, or even reading this post to please **read** the documents on the following two links:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-use-gridfs

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/

The summary is, the **sole** purpose of GridFS is to be able to store content **larger** than the **16MB** BSON document limit. In essence the document gets **chunked** into smaller (than 16MB) parts and inserted into a special collection. This facilitates handling the size limit on both read and write with a simplified interface to get at all the documents required.

The extra information is that GridFS is **not** MongoDB magic. The **server** knows nothing of the information stored other than it is just another document. So GridFS is a **driver** spec implementation, meaning that each read and write results in **multiple document requests** over the wire.

Now the real point is, when your content is **under 16MB** then you are better off just inserting it as data in a normal document field (binary will need to be base64 encoded of course), and all you reads and writes happen in **one shot** over the wire.

For this implementation case, where your **images** are under 16MB, you would get a single document back, with a field, containing a String, which would be simple to stream parse (from base64) and return the content. Or basically anything on the conversion as you need not worry with additional calls going back to the MongoDB server for more "chunks".

If you **really** need 200MB High Res Photoshop documents as your data source then by all means, go ahead and use GridFS. It's probably what you want in that case.

Not bagging GridFS, It's a really good idea. It's just that most people who are using it are not using it for what it was designed for.

P.S Your real problem with doing any streaming conversion is you'd need several pieces of meta data about the image (typical not available from library methods until the whole file content can be accessed) in order to do this. So you would be storing custom information anyway in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hmm. Hope someone else up-votes. Then I'll have privilege to create a GridFS tag.

Comment: Actually I've developed a file manager which allows user to manage files no matter what type and how large it is. So maybe I have to store files more that 16MB. It's easier for me to store both small and big file in GridFS with the same infrastructure as it doesn't have much overhead IMO. So the final question is that OK, how can I get a simple stream from an `Enumerator`.

Comment: Or maybe it's better to be asked in another question!?

Comment: @A.Karimi Probably so, as far as the other question goes. But You **shouldn't** consider your infrastructure on **maybe** because that always leads to poor decisions. Some flexibility is fine, but keep the  implementation within the use case. My response is largely prompted from you mentioning "images" in the post. So we are talking Web, and we are talking less than 16MB. (Who's going to wait?). It's a very valid comment I have repeated many times. You **don't** want GridFS for that, the performance problems will kill you.

Comment: right, but I'm sure we will have some files bigger than 16M but they are absolutely not images (Docs, PDF, ...). So you mean I should have a collection for image files and use GridFS for others?

Comment: Why use base64 and not BinData?

Comment: @frant.hartm Your're right. I shouldn't be opinionated. What ever format you want that BSON expects. I've seen people pull out the Base64 strings and embed directly in HTML/CSS, so I guess that would save an encoding step when it is already encoded.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, storing and fetching binary data into/from GridFS makes always sense as MongoDB/ReactiveMongo answers a query with a 'stream' of whole documents. Having (potential huge) binary data stored in one single document doesn't allow to really stream the data. Instead the binary data is read into memory completely first which isn't a good idea due to resource limitations.

So back to your original question, the main problem here is basically how to connect an OutputStream (which an Iteratee might write into) to an InputStream that is needed by the image processing library. See http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html for details.

The following code should explain the concept hopefully:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.Arrays
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

object StreamingDemo extends App {

  // this enumerator will come from GridFS in your scenario
  val enumerator = Enumerator[Array[Byte]](Array(1, 2), Array(3), Array(4, 5, 6)) andThen Enumerator.eof

  val in = new PipedInputStream();
  val out = new PipedOutputStream(in);

  def putDataOnOutputStream(out: OutputStream) = {
    // as we have a Future here writing to the OutputStream is done in a separate thread as needed with piping
    enumerator.apply(Iteratee.foreach { elem =>
      println("write...");
      out.write(elem)
      out.flush()
    }).onComplete { _ =>
      out.close()
    }
  }

  def processDataFromInputStream(in: InputStream) = {
    var res: Int = in.read
    while (res != -1) {
      println("read: " + res);
      res = in.read
    }
    in.close()
  }

  putDataOnOutputStream(out)
  processDataFromInputStream(in);

}
```